# Using multiple CTEs in one statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I want to use multiple CTEs in my query, but I haven't been able to get it working. The following is an example of what I would like to do:

```
WITH tbl1 AS
    (SELECT *
    FROM tblStuff)

WITH tbl2 AS
    (SELECT tbl1.fldStuff1 ...
     FROM tbl1, tblStuff2)

    SELECT *
    FROM tbl2
```

Comment: Mine is time stamped ahead of yours? Why so angry today @AaronBertrand? You're better than this :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
WITH tbl1 AS
    (SELECT *
    FROM tblStuff),

tbl2 AS
    (SELECT tbl1.fldStuff1, tbl1.fldStuff2, tblStuff2.fldStuff1, tblStuff2.fldStuff2
     FROM tbl1, tblStuff2)

    SELECT *
    FROM tbl2
```

When you use multiple CTEs, no need for the extra WITH, seperate with a comma.

Comment: -1 for not terminating your statement with a `;`. [Reference](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons)

Comment: +1 for referencing Aaron's blog for this.

Comment: Yeah, well he's smart.

Comment: Well, someone down-voted both of our answers, twice each. Not sure what the problem is, or whether karma has been involved, or what. But multiple not-so-nice things have happened here today.

Comment: If it helps, I haven't down-voted you. I'm tempted to delete mine, but now it's the accepted answer I don't know :/

Comment: @Meff If you do, I will FedEx overnight one American made product.

Answer (score 15):

You only need to specify `WITH` once. Then you can list additional CTEs separated by a comma. E.g.:

```
WITH cte1 AS 
(
  ...
),
cte2 AS 
(
  ...
)
SELECT ...;
```